# simple way to implement business tier for Php app

Tags: web-services, hibernate, spring, cakephp, ejb-3.0

We are in the process of redesigning a php app that uses MY SQL and cakephp as the app framework.

- One of the redesign goals is to support a **multi-tenant model** , 
  where n clients , each with an **identical database schema** (i.e 1 database per tenant) can use the **hosted application**.
- Based on the login credentials, the front end (php layer) will make a call to the business layer (EJB/Web
  Service etc).
- The business layer will then return relevant JSON data that is then rendered by cakephp
- Today all the work is done by cakephp and this model is not scaling well for dynamic changes, suited to an individual tenant.

> Questions:
>
> 1. Is this a good design pattern - i.e have a php frontend serviced
>      by a Java business tier ?
> 2. What are some good candidates for the business tier. We would like
>      to keep it as   simple as possible - ideally use Tomcat and not go
>      with a full fledged EJB solution if we can. I envision the business
>      layer to consist of many session bean type of objects.
> 3. Can we get away with  a business tier that just serves up JSON via
>      REST Web Services ? There is no transaction beyond - reading a whole
>      bunch of data to render a few pages, lots of AJAX updates , and some
>      non Ajax posts.
> 4. What features in Java EE 6 make this design possible (if any) 
>      without Spring/EJB.
> 5. Considering Hibernate/myBatis as ORM in business tier. Solution
>      should seamlessly support this.

All thoughts welcome.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Web services will be more interoperable than EJBs.  They use HTTP as the protocol; that's what  browser based UIs use.  If you go with EJBs, which are based on RMI, you'll have to wrap them to accept HTTP requests.

I would prefer a Spring/POJO approach that uses Spring "contract first" web services for the back end services.   I greatly prefer Spring to EJB.

I wouldn't jump to Hibernate unless you have a solid object model to map to and the complexity warrants it.  I'd bet that straight JDBC or perhaps iBatis would be more than sufficient.